# What is numerical solution to get the inverse of the special matrix with many repeated elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, inverse

The question is about how to get the inverse of the matrix via numerical method.
\begin{bmatrix}
0.3677 &0.1347  &-0.0871  &-0.0871  &-0.0706  &-0.0706 \\ 
 0.1347&0.3677  &-0.0871  &-0.0871  &-0.0706  &-0.0706 \\ 
 -0.0871&-0.0871  &0.4154  &0.1824  &-0.1183  &-0.1183 \\ 
 -0.0871&-0.0871  &0.1824  &0.4154  &-0.1183  &-0.1183 \\ 
 -0.0706&-0.0706  &-0.1183  &-0.1183  &0.3989  &0.1659 \\ 
 -0.0706& -0.0706 &-0.1183  &-0.1183  &0.1659  &0.3989 
\end{bmatrix}

I have obtained the inverse using MATLAB, and the result shows a strong regularity. I must write codes to solve the problem in an embedded controller(MCU) so numerical solution is needed.

Could somebody give a hint? Thanks!

Comment: "A general n×n matrix can be inverted using methods such as the Gauss-Jordan elimination, Gaussian elimination, or LU decomposition." http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html

Comment: Or Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion

Comment: You'd probably want to implement LU-decomposition. For implementation details, it's probably better to ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I know that LU decomposition is a general method to solve the inverse. But I want to know whether there exists a specific numerical solution for my matrix because it has many repeated elements and the result given by MATLAB shows a strong regularity.

Comment: If I understand well, you mean that one recognizes a **block structure** in your matrix, and your question is "can we take advantage of this block structure to get in a quicker way its inverse". Is that the challenge ? (being assumed that the numerical values of the matrix are not the same each time, but the $3 \times 3$ overall block structure always remain the same ?)

Answer (score 1):

You may express your matrix as a rank-3 update to a diagonal one
$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 g & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & g & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & h & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & h & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 b & d & e \\
 c & e & f \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
M = D + U C U^\top
$$
and apply [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)
$$
M^{-1} = D^{-1} - D^{-1} U \left(
C^{-1} + U^\top D^{-1} U
\right)^{-1} U^\top D^{-1}.
$$

This operation cost is two inverses of $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices ($C$ and $C^{-1} + U^\top D^{-1} U$). Inversions of diagonal matrices are trivial.

But if you need simple code for a controller I suggest implementing some simple factorization algorithms, like [Cholesky or $LDL^\top$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is elegant. I want to know how do you think of the decomposition m=d+ucu^t?

Comment: I was looking for a decomposition in the form "simply invertible matrix" and "low rank matrix" to apply Woodbury identity. Matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & a & b & b & c & c\\
a & a & b & b & c & c\\
b & b & d & d & e & e\\
b & b & d & d & e & e\\
c & c & e & e & f & f\\
c & c & e & e & f & f
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is low rank since it has duplicate rows and columns. Matrix $U$ is simply duplicating rows or columns depending on multiplying side.